# Using the same first argument in a Ramda pipe

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Is it possible to compose the following function in [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/)?

`(a, b) => R.pipe(func1(a), func2(a))(b)`

The aim is passing argument `a` to all functions in the `pipe`.

My initial thought was the following:

`R.pipe(R.juxt([func1, func2]), R.apply(R.pipe))`

But this gives `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier to express using [`S.pipe`](https://sanctuary.js.org/#pipe) as it takes an *array* of functions to compose.

One option is to use [`R.ap`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#juxt):

```
> S.pipe(R.ap([S.add, S.mult, S.add], [3]), 10)
42
```

Another option is to use [`R.map`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) with [`S.T`](https://sanctuary.js.org/#T), the thrush combinator:

```
> S.pipe(R.map(S.T(3), [S.add, S.mult, S.add]), 10)
42
```

You could then wrap one of these in a lambda to create a binary function:

```
const f = (a, b) => S.pipe(R.ap([S.add, S.mult, S.add], [a]), b);

f(3, 10);  // add(3)(mult(3)(add(3)(10)))
// => 42
```

Comment: Thanks, my solution from your answer: `R.pipe(R.of, R.ap([R.assoc('b'), R.assoc('c')]), R.apply(R.pipe))(2)({a:1}) //= {a: 1, b: 2, c: 2}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a curried version of all the functions, then call the curried version of each with `a` and finally use `b` in either `R.pipe` or `R.reduce`

Let's say that the functions that need to have `a` as the first argument are `f,g,h` (in that specific order) then we want to achieve the following expression

```
h(a, g(a, f(a, b)))
```

---

First of all let's create a curried function which receives two arguments, a single value `v` and a function `fn`, when this function receives all its required arguments it will simply return `fn(v)`

```
const rev = R.curry((v, fn) => fn(v))
```

Next we can create the curried versions of the functions with `R.map` and `R.curry`

```
// note the reversed order of the functions
// I'll use R.compose instead of R.pipe
let curriedVersion = R.map(R.curry, [h,g,f])
```

However we also need to use `a` as the first argument of the curried functions, we could call each curried function with `a` using `R.map` but instead we will use our special function `rev`

```
const curriedVersion = R.map(R.compose(rev(a), R.curry), [h,g,f])
```

Finally let's use this array of curried functions with `R.compose` and `b`

```
const result = R.compose.apply(undefined, curriedVersion)(b)
```

One liner (for the functions `f,g,h` in that specific order):

```
const solver = (a, b) => R.compose.apply(undefined, R.map(R.compose(rev(a), R.curry), [h,g,f]))(b)
```

```js
const add = (a, b) => a + b
const sub = (a, b) => a - b
const mul = (a, b) => a * b

const rev = R.curry((v, fn) => fn(v))
const solver = (a, b) => R.compose.apply(undefined, R.map(R.compose(rev(a), R.curry), [mul,sub,add]))(b)

// mul(2, sub(2, add(2, 3)))
// mul(2, sub(2, 5))
// mul(2, -3)
// -6
console.log(solver(2, 3))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.21.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I suggest using [`R.apply`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#apply) rather than `R.compose.apply(undefined, …)`.